# How to change the charset for one table in Symfony and Doctrine ORM?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Do all database tables have to have the same charset when using Symfony and Doctrine ORM or is there a possibility to set the charset for each table individually? How?

I just changed the charset for one database table from `utf8` to `utf8mb4` but it only seems to work properly if I also configure `doctrine.dbal.charset` to `utf8mb4` in `config.yaml`.

I also tried to solve my problem by using this annotation in the Entity class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(
 *     name="my_table_name",
 *     options={
 *         "charset": "utf8mb4",
 *         "collate": "utf8mb4_general_ci"
 *     }
 * )
 */
```

Comment: Doctrine [does not support](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/faq.html#database-schema) this kind of granular character set or collation mapping configuration and expects you to [manage this yourself manually](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/7485#issue-383447645).

Comment: @JeroenvanderLaan What `doctrine.dbal.charset` configuration should I then use when I manually set some tables to `utf8` and others to `utf8mb4`?

Comment: I am no expert on this subject, but if possible I recommend migrating your entire database to use `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8` (aka the deprecated `utf8mb3`) entirely, and then set `utf8mb4` as the default Doctrine character set. If this is not possible however, then you'd have to configure Doctrine to keep assuming `utf8` instead.

Comment: Did you try to make more connections? I think that is only possible solution for handling tables with different encoding. After that you have access to multiple *EntityManager* and its up to you to choose one with proper encoding. It is unpleasant, but using different encoding for tables is very strange and mostly there is no requirement to do that. Maybe you can describe your use case and we can try to find solution for you.